# Why does PySpark get stuck after completing few ShuffleMapTasks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs

I use pyspark run a python script, when executing the **"14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 6)"** there is no reaction, and has been stuck in here, there is no error message。

==========log=============

```
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:4 as 3689 bytes in 1 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:5 as TID 73 on executor 0: myhost-bigdata-110d13 (NODE_LOCAL)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:5 as 3689 bytes in 0 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:6 as TID 74 on executor 2: myhost-bigdata-110d14 (NODE_LOCAL)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:6 as 3689 bytes in 0 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:7 as TID 75 on executor 1: myhost-bigdata-110d12 (NODE_LOCAL)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:7 as 3689 bytes in 0 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:8 as TID 76 on executor 0: myhost-bigdata-110d13 (NODE_LOCAL)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:8 as 3689 bytes in 0 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:9 as TID 77 on executor 2: myhost-bigdata-110d14 (NODE_LOCAL)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:9 as 3689 bytes in 0 ms
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 73 in 200 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d13 (progress: 0/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 5)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 76 in 218 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d13 (progress: 1/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 8)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 72 in 324 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d12 (progress: 2/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 4)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 69 in 371 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d12 (progress: 3/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 1)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 75 in 367 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d12 (progress: 4/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 7)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 77 in 423 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d14 (progress: 5/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 9)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 71 in 435 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d14 (progress: 6/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 3)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 74 in 510 ms on myhost-bigdata-110d14 (progress: 7/10)
14/03/23 21:00:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ShuffleMapTask(5, 6)
```

==============work1 log==============

```
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 59 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 59 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 47 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 59
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 47 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 47
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 44 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 44 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 44
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 82, boot = 3, init = 76, finish = 3
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 65 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 65 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 65
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 68
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 68
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 71
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 71
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 74
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 74
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 77
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 77
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00000.bz2:0+14685
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00009.bz2:0+15447
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00006.bz2:0+14924
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00003.bz2:0+15015
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 89, boot = 3, init = 62, finish = 24
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 68 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 68 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 68
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 83, boot = 2, init = 57, finish = 24
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 77 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 77 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:33 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 77
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 66, boot = 2, init = 40, finish = 24
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 95, boot = 2, init = 60, finish = 33
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 71 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 71 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 71
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 74 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 74 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:34 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 74
```

=========work2 log ========================

```
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 60 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 60 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 60
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 69
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 69
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 72
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 72
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 75
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 75
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00001.bz2:0+14114
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00007.bz2:0+15325
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00004.bz2:0+15169
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO python.PythonRDD: stdin writer to Python finished early
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO python.PythonRDD: stdin writer to Python finished early
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 25, boot = 2, init = 10, finish = 13
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 72 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 72 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:40 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 72
```

===============work3 log===================

```
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 55 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 61 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 55 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 58
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 55
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 61 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 61
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 92, boot = 3, init = 86, finish = 3
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 67 is 968
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 67 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 67
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 64 is 962
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 64 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:28 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 64
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 70
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 70
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 73
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 73
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 76
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 76
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block broadcast_0 locally
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00002.bz2:0+14560
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00008.bz2:0+14842
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://myhost-bigdata-110d11:9000/tmp/logs/2014/03/21/cc/uv/part-00005.bz2:0+14961
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 73, boot = 3, init = 46, finish = 24
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 70 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 70 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 70
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 73, boot = 2, init = 47, finish = 24
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 76 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 76 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 76
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO python.PythonRDD: Times: total = 78, boot = 3, init = 47, finish = 28
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 73 is 851
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 73 directly to driver
14/03/23 21:32:29 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 73
```

=============my code============

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://myhost-bigdata:7077")
conf.setAppName("job")
conf.set("spark.ui.port", 4040)
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

types = ["pv","uv"]
for type in types:
    dm = sc.textFile("/tmp/uv/part-%s-*.gz" % type)
    arrs1 = dm.map(lambda line: (int(line.split("^")[0].split("_")[0]),line.split("^")[1])).distinct().map(lambda a:( a[0], 1)).countByKey().items()
    arrs2 = dm.map(lambda line: (int(line.split("^")[0].split("_")[1]),line.split("^")[1])).distinct().map(lambda a:( a[0], 1)).countByKey().items()
    arrs3 = dm.map(lambda line: (int(line.split("^")[0].split("_")[2]),line.split("^")[1])).distinct().map(lambda a:( a[0], 1)).countByKey().items()
```

=====================my new code ==================

```
#-*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
import logging
import time
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

logger = logging.getLogger("endlesscode")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', )
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("y.log")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def getSparkContext(port):
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("spark://my-bigdata-01:7077")
    conf.setAppName("test")
    conf.set("spark.ui.port", port)
    return SparkContext(conf=conf)


def getPv(dm, level):
    return dm.map(
        lambda line: (int(line.split("^")[0].split("_")[level]), int(line.split("^")[1]))).reduceByKey(
        lambda a, b: a + b, numPartitions=80).collect()


def getUv(dm, level):
    return dm.map(
        lambda line: (int(line.split("^")[0].split("_")[level]), line.split("^")[1])).distinct().map(
        lambda a: (a[0], 1)).reduceByKey(
        lambda a, b: a + b, numPartitions=80).collect()


def calc(ls):
    sc = []
    try:
        port = ls[0]
        cityname = ls[1]
        calcTime = ls[2]
        regDate = calcTime[0] + "-" + calcTime[1] + "-" + calcTime[2]
        logNames = ["pcpv", "wappv", "apppv", "pcuv", "wapuv", "appuv", "hottidall"]
        sc = getSparkContext(port)
        for index, ln in enumerate(logNames):
            log = "/tmp/2014report/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/part-*.bz2" % (calcTime[0], calcTime[1], calcTime[2], cityname, ln)
            dm = sc.textFile(log)
            logger.debug("Type: %s, total count: %s; cityname: %s; first: %s" % (ln, dm.count(), cityname, dm.take(1)))
            if index in (0, 1, 2):
                for i in range(0, 3):
                    result = getPv(dm, i)
                    logger.debug("Level: %s, regDate: %s, cityname: %s, result: %s", i, regDate, cityname, result)
            elif index in (3, 4, 5):
                for i in range(0, 3):
                    result = getUv(dm, i)
                    logger.debug("Level: %s, regDate: %s, cityname: %s, result: %s", i, regDate, cityname, result)
            elif index == 6:
                pass
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error: %s", e)
    finally:
        sc.stop()


def getAllCityName():
    array = ("cc", "hangzhou", "taizhou", "jiaxing") 
    return array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 5100
    curTime = time.time()
    citynames = getAllCityName()
    for index1, cityname in enumerate(citynames):
        calc((port + index1, cityname, ["2014", "03", "26"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It only has 10 partitions `(progress: 7/10)`.  If the data is really big, then a shuffle could get out of hand with only 10 partitions.  I've found my jobs often hang when I have very Big Data and not enough partitions.  The hang might be caused by mental GC hang, or something memory related.  You want about 2 - 4 partitions per CPU, but sometimes I use more than that to stop OOMs and crazy GC hangs, like 1000s.

Also `countByKey` doesn't scale in the number of keys, that can be a problem.  Try (Scala code) `.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)`

Comment: gc normal, enough memory

Comment: I try to set "spark.default.parallelism = 40",  it is still the same

Comment: You mean it still only has 10 partitions, or still hangs?? If the latter at what stage does it hang, does it get past 7??

Comment: it still hangs.partitions will automatically change, sometimes 5, sometimes 40

Comment: It is now "(progress: 3/5)" hangs

Comment: hmm, idk y it would change between 5 and 40.  When it runs with 40 partitions at what stage does it crash?. 40 may still be too small, how many GB you have? and how many cores your have?

You may also be hitting a problem by using `countByKeys()` which doesn't scale in the number of keys.  Try using (Scala code) `.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)`.

Comment: server 24 core,64g memeory. 40 partitions without crashing. it then either hang "(progress: 3/5)"

Comment: I try to set "spark.default.parallelism = 100", it is still the same

Comment: What is the size of the data? How many keys are there?  Anyway, `spark.default.parallelism` doesn't seem to necessarily change the partitions.  You can force the partition count with: `sc.textFile(path, numPartitions)` or `sc.textFile(path).repartition(numPartitions)`.

Comment: data about 1G. key about 17574208+

Comment: I try to use `sc.textFile(path, 20)`,  it is now "(progress: 21/23)" hang

Comment: Well you won't be able to use countByKey with that many keys, a map like that will struggle to fit into memory. You'll have to use .reduceByKey as I said.  And as I said you want 2 - 4 tasks per CPU, so ~100 partitions will be better.

Comment: I try to use `reduceByKey()`, 80 partitions. the result is still the same

Comment: Try increasing your frame size to 500